# MTP Driver fails to install for CM 10.1 on Samsung Galaxy Note II

Tags: cyanogenmod, windows, usb-drivers, mtp, samsung-galaxy-note-2

The nightly builds of CyanogenMod 10.1 for the Samsung Galaxy Note II was just released.

I have been using CM on my devices since the G1 (ADP1) days so I decided to give it a try.

I have only had 2 issues so far. (Bluetooth is wonky but I don't use it very often)

1. Lack of support for ExFAT. This was easily worked around by converting my SDCard to FAT32. While I wish there was support for ExFAT, I doubt there ever will be since it is a propitary format that was licensed to Samsung.
2. Unable to successfully install the MTP drivers (Windows 7). I have tried rebooting, uninstalling the "existing" drivers and rebooting. Nothing seems to allow the driver to successfully install.

It goes through the entire process of installing the driver. It even downloads it from Microsoft Update after I uninstall the existing driver. But it will not successfully install.

[image: MTP USB Device: Failed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all that I needed to do was reboot my PC. Once I rebooted my PC had no problems installing the MTP driver for the device.

Answer (score 0):

One of my PCs was having this same problem while my other laptop was without any problem, I have notice that the problem would disappear after I re-install the Samsung mobile driver back. I am not sure why this was a problem. I think that the problem is with windows, since another PC could detect it without any issues.